# How can I make cmake not to delete object files so that I could quickly change between debug/release?

Tags: cmake

I frequently change between debug and release build of a large-ish library. Whenever I issue a

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG
```

or the same with RELEASE and do a make, everything is recompiling. I'd like cmake to recompile only the files changed since I built last time with the given mode. Can I do that, and if so, how?

I am using OSX and clang.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the most common solution is have independent build directories for each compile mode (options).

I mean that you need create two directories for this purpose (if your source code stored in `ProjectSrc`):

```
ProjectSrc  
└── CMakeList.txt  
ProjectBuild_Debug  
ProjectBuild_Release
```

Inside `ProjectBuild_Debug` you need call:

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../ProjectSrc`

And Inside `ProjectBuild_Release` you need call:

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../ProjectSrc`

Now you can rebuild any type of your program and only files which was changed will be recompiled.

`everything is recompiling` - everything is recompiling because each file must be compiled with specified compiler options and it's necessary.

Let's look together. For example our project, which build executable file `program.exe` consist from two source files: `one.cpp` and `two.cpp`, both of them have debug output.

1. You build with `release` options:
   `one.o` and `two.o`.
2. You change file `one.cpp` and rebuild with `debug` . Now if `CMake` rebuild only changed files you will get situation when you expect debug version of your `program.exe` with correct debug output, but it is not, because debug output in file `two.o` was disabled according last time compilation options.

Comment: I don't really want to change build directory if I don't have to, but changing the object file's directory would suffice, I think. Which option does that?

Comment: I'm sorry my English is horrendous. I don't clearly understand you question. Do you want store object files in different directories but build executable in the same place?

Comment: Yes. Executable file is expected to be in it's former place (it is a library which is copied elsewhere by a script after build).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to achieve this goal. It seams to me that you need declare custom `CMake` directive `add_custom_command`. [This question looks like related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994045/copy-target-file-to-another-location-in-a-post-build-step-in-cmake).