# Automatically copy executable to directory after build in CLion? (using CMake)

Tags: build, cmake, clion

How can I make CLion automatically copy my compiled executable to a specified directory after each build?

Since CLion uses CMake, I guess this should be possible with some CMake command in the CMakeLists.txt file. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know about CLion but generally you can add this as a [post-build step](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_custom_command.html) to an [executable target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_executable.html) in CMake with:

```
add_executable(MyExe ...)
add_custom_command(TARGET MyExe 
                   POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:MyExe> SomeOtherDir)
```

See e.g. [Copy target file to another location in a post build step in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994045/copy-target-file-to-another-location-in-a-post-build-step-in-cmake)

Comment: Can you explain what I am supposed to fill in here?

Comment: MyExe is your executable's target name, in my example from `add_executable(MyExe ...)`. You just add the above custom command after the `add_executable()` line to your `CMakeLists.txt`. It will take the full path of your executable (see [generator expressions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#informational-expressions)) and will copy it to `SomeOtherDir`. If you don't give a full path as `SomeOtherDir` it will be relative to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`.

Answer (score 6):

My favorite option is to generate the executable in the right folder directly as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994045/copy-target-file-to-another-location-in-a-post-build-step-in-cmake):

the secret is to use the target property `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`. This has per-configuration options (e.g. RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG).

```
set_target_properties(mylibrary PROPERTIES
                      RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG <debug path>
                      RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE <release path>
)
```

See [this link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) for more information.

However you can run on your terminal also:

```
cmake --help-property "RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY"
cmake --help-property "RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>"
```

To copy the executable after the compilation is a good working solution.

Comment: This is actually a really neat way of doing it!

Answer (score 4):

I use CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY. it will be the place where your output is going to compile. if you need to do another copy, then you will need to do tricks.

`set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_PATH}/bin/client/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})`

Answer (score 0):

[`EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH.html) is what eventually worked for my purpose.

```
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "/my/output/dir/")
add_executable(foo foo.c)
```

Although [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH.html) for `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` says

> Old executable location variable.
>
> The target property RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY supersedes this variable
> for a target if it is set. Executable targets are otherwise placed in
> this directory.

setting `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` doesn't seem to have any effect for me, but setting `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` does.

I am using the latest release of cmake.

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.28.1
```