# How to determine current build type of visual studio with cmake

Tags: visual-studio, dll, cmake

I don't know how to configure multiple build types in Visual Studio with Cmake.
For example, when *debug* is selected in Visual Studio, I need to copy `*d.dll` to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/rundir/debug/bin` and when *release* is selected in Visual Studio, I need to copy `*.dll` to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/rundir/release/bin`.

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean _copy_ in the sense of a _post-success-build_ or as an actual _install_ step? You know, you can use generator expressions to specify a build-type-dependent location?

Comment: Is the DLL the product of another target?

Comment: .I found the solution. I use $(configuration) variable of visual studio in cmake like this:                                                               add_custom_command(TARGET obs POST_BUILD 
  COMMAND if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
  xcopy /y /d  "$(QTDIR)\\bin\\Qt5WebKitWidgetsd.dll" "$(SolutionDir)rundir\\$(Configuration)\\bin\\64bit"       \n   )                          else                                                                                                                            (//DO something)

Comment: You could add/edit that to your question to improve it a little bit. There is only one problem with your solution: It isn't platform independent and VS-/MSBuild-centric. I've posted an answer using CMake's platform abstraction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy target file to another location in a post build step in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994045/copy-target-file-to-another-location-in-a-post-build-step-in-cmake)

Answer (score 3):

As you want a *post-build* action, there is a CMake command and also the appropriate variables available.

The platform independent command to copy around files with CMake is using [CMake itself on the command line](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode):

```
${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "${src}" "${dest}"
```

The "current" configuration can be extracted with [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html):

```
$<CONFIG>
```

and even directly tested for trueness

```
$<CONFIG:Debug>
```

The output directory for a target's binaries (i.e. executables and shared libraries/DLLs) is given with the target property [`RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) (and `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>`) which are pre-populated with the global variable [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) (and `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>`).

Finally, we can compose the post-build command

```
add_custom_command(TARGET myTarget POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND if $<CONFIG:Debug> ("${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy_if_different "${path_to_dependent_dll}/dependent.dll" "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG}")
                   COMMAND if $<CONFIG:Release> ("${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy_if_different "${path_to_dependent_dll}/dependent.dll" "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE}")
                   COMMENT "Copying dependent DLL"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer was very usefull for me, but it didn't work for me so I maid these modifications to make it work:

- I replaced `if $<CONFIG:Debug>` by `if $<CONFIG:Debug> neq 0`, the same for `if $<CONFIG:Release>`
- `${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG}` and `${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE}` where not defined in my case, so I replaced them by `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:myTarget>`