# CMake post-build-event: copy compiled libraries

Tags: cmake

The binary directory structure of my project is currently like this (Windows):

```
bin/mainProject/{Debug,Release}
bin/library1/{Debug,Release}
bin/library2/{Debug,Release}
...
bin/libraryN/{Debug,Release}
```

I'd like to copy the libraries `library1lib.dll`, ... `libraryNlib.dll` to the `bin/mainProject/{Debug,Release}` directory once they are build.

For CMake, I think this is doable using a post-build event, hence I've tried adding this to each of the libraries' `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET library1 POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/library1lib.dll
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mainProject/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/
)
```

Currently, there are two issues:

1. `${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}` seems to be not defined, at least I get an empty string for that variable in the output window.
2. Is there a possibility to make that post-build event more generic? Like replacing the actual dll name with some variable?

Comment: Highly related and possible dup target: ["_Copy target file to another location in a post build step in CMake_"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9994045/11107541).

Comment: Also note the existence of the [`RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html), [`LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html), and [`ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) config variables, and the corresponding [`RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_CONFIG.html), etc. config variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy DLL files into the same folder as the executable using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake)

Answer (score 8):

You can make this more generic by using [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html):

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET library1 
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
        $<TARGET_FILE:library1>
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:mainProject>/$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:library1>
)
```

**Alternative**

You could - if every dependency is build within your CMake project - also just give a common output path for all executables and DLLs with something like:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Out")
```

*Note:* The absolute path is required here because it would otherwise be relative to each targets default output path. And note that the configuration's sub-directory is appended by CMake automatically.

**References**

- [How to copy DLL files into the same folder as the executable using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake)

Comment: It does seem that in many cases CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY will be the appropriate solution. If you're following the so-called "Modern CMake" method of using target properties instead of global variables, you can set the property [RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) on each target.