# CMake Windows implicit linking

Tags: cmake

What is the defacto way of handling implicit linking in CMake projects?

In windows, `.dll`'s are linked during runtime, thus CMake only needs to link the `.lib` files during compilation. This is better done using `find_package`. However, during compilation, CMake never copies over the `.dll` corresponding to the linked `.lib` file to the linked executable's output path.

Is this something that CMake leaves up to the user?

It seems kind of messy, not to mention non-cross platform, to have to manually find `dll`'s for each library you link and either manually copy them over to your output directory or write individual CMake commands, as shown below, to do this per package you find/library you link.

```
add_custom_command(
        TARGET MyTarget POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/SDL2.dll"
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyTarget>
    )
```

Comment: [They suggest](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Copying-of-3rd-party-DLLs-in-a-POST-BUILD-step-tp7167258p7168360.html) to use CMake modules [BundleUtilities](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/BundleUtilities.html) or [GetPrerequisites](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/GetPrerequisites.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy DLL files into the same folder as the executable using CMake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake) or [CMake post-build-event: copy compiled libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696990/cmake-post-build-event-copy-compiled-libraries)

Comment: But I see this more as a limitation of the build tool/operating system. So why is Visual Studio not able to copy its C++ DLL dependencies like it's doing for C# dependencies? See also [How to make Visual Studio copy a DLL file to the output directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776060/how-to-make-visual-studio-copy-a-dll-file-to-the-output-directory), VS also uses post-build actions. I also found [the following approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005901/how-to-set-path-environment-variable-using-cmake-and-visual-studio-to-run-test) interesting.

Comment: @Florian VS does have a function for post-build actions, however, this needs to be handled at the CMake level because CMake needs to be able to generate such projects for many different IDEs not just VS.