# How to set a post build command to VS project from cmake?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, post-build-event

I need to set this post-build event in cmake

how to do this?

I am using below command in my vs project, but I need to add it during CMake build in **Cmakelists.txt**

```
xcopy /y /d "$(TargetPath)" "$(ProjectDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)"
```

I tried following but they didn't work for me VS cannot find the path

[How to copy DLL files into the same folder as the executable using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake)

[CMake post-build-event: copy compiled libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696990/cmake-post-build-event-copy-compiled-libraries)

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET my 
    POST_BUILD        
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} xcopy /y /d "$(TargetPath)" "$(ProjectDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)" 
)
```

error --> this $(ProjectDir)$(Platform)$(Configuration) not giving right path it shows x64Debug not x64\Debug

Comment: So, you have tried to put your command into `add_custom_command(POST_BUILD)` event, haven't you? Please, show (add to the question post) what exactly have you tried. If that attempt results with an error, then show that error too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev i have updated

Comment: The backslash should escaped: ``\\``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as explained in the above comment

```
backslash should escaped: \\ 

add_custom_command(TARGET my POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
    "$(TargetPath)"
    "$(ProjectDir)$(Platform)\\$(Configuration)" 
)
```